# How to leave navbar out of certain page? React web

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, routes

**How to not show a navbar in the pages result 1-5 while showing it in all the other pages, is it possible to change it in this file ? **

```
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
        <Route path="/Aboutus" component={Aboutus} />
        <Route path="/Contactus" component={ContactUs} />



        <Route path="/selecttemplate" component={SelectT} />
        }/>
        }/>
        }/>
      </Switch>
    </div>
    <Route path="/result1" component={Result1} />
    <Route className='FullHeight' path="/result2" component={Result2} />
    <Route className='FullHeight' path="/result3" component={Result3} />
    <Route className='FullHeight' path="/result4" component={Result4} />
    <Route className='FullHeight' path="/result5" component={Result5} />
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

}
}

Comment: Hi Zaina, you need to provide more details in order for us to help you. Also, as is your posted code is incorrect, as the Navbar needs to be inside of the first switch statement

Answer (score 0):

```
this.props.location returns currently opened url.
```

so you can check current url and render NavBar conditionally.
if current url is equal to those url's in which you don't want to show navbar return null else return navbar

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div>
     {
       ((this.props.history.location === '/') || (this.props.location === '/Aboutus')
       || (this.props.history.location === '/Contactus') || 
       (this.props.history.location === '/selecttemplate') || 
       (this.props.history.location === '/result1')) ? null : <Navbar />
     }
    <Switch>
     .
     .
     .
```